# server execution failed- 2012 server r2 standard

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have problem with my server 2012 r2.when i trying to add new roles and features server manager showing an error server execution failed. the same error is there with auto refresh of server manager.from the event viewer i got this message server did not registered with DCOM within required time out.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Rebooting fixed it, since it seemed that there were some server updates that required a reboot to install. After that, Roles and Features would continue as expected.